# Vimscript: How to check if a buffer is modified

Tags: vimscript, buffers

Given a buffer number `i`, I want to check if the buffer has been modified after the last save. How do I do that in vimscript?

**I tried** to use `getbufvar()` like the following:

```
if getbufvar(i, "&modified")
  echo "Modified"
else
  echo "Not Modified"
endif
```

but this always seems to `echo` "Modified". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I fail to see why `getbufvar(bufnr, '&mod')` fails to work in your case. Are you sure you're using the right buffer id? For instance, in some autocommand cases, it's easy to get confused and use `'%'` instead of `<amatch>`

Comment: Luc is right. Your problem lies somewhere else. The most typical error is `getbufvar(expand('<abuf>'), ...)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could work with `getbufinfo()`. Note that this function always returns a list of dictionaries.

```
if getbufinfo(i)[0].changed
    echo "Modified"
else
    echo "Not Modified"
endif
```

Note that this will fail, if the buffer with the number `i` does not exist.

BTW: If you want to know all changed buffers do:

```
for buf in getbufinfo({'bufmodified': 1})
    echo buf.bufnr
endfor
```

If you want to know about the current buffer do:

```
if getbufinfo('%')[0].changed
    echo "Modified"
else
    echo "Not modified"
endif
```

See `:h getbufinfo` for the details.

Comment: Or `:echo getbufinfo({'bufmodified': 1})->map({ _, b -> b.bufnr })->join(',')`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Is that supposed to work as is? It's getting me an "using List as String" error.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I can get `echo join(map(getbufinfo({'bufmodified': 1}), { _,b  -> b.bufnr }),",")` to work, but not with the `->` syntax.

Comment: @PSkocik it works for me; perhaps your vim is a little older and you don't have method syntax. In either case, it's syntax sugar for what you wrote.